# Как добавить fadeIn эффект?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет! Хочу добавить эффект фэйдинга чтобы, когда прокручиваешь страницу вниз элементы начинали появляться. На данный момент в скрипте есть `.animate()` эффект, но хочется именно фэйд попробовать, но почему-то не могу сделать этого. Вот сам скрипт и код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each(function(i) {

      var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

      /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 1500);

      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hideme {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hideme">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
<div class="hideme">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
<div class="hideme">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: добавить класс и через css - transition + opacity: 1 - Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/pyh4e6fk/

Comment: попроще было бы использовать что-то по типу https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic

Comment: Я сколько не пытаюсьустановить эти плагины, вечно, что-то не так....